# Sodium Hydroxide additives?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

We use a 10-15% site made sodium hydroxide solution to remove extruded aluminum residue in a boil out tank from steel tooling in an extrusion press. Our old nitrate/nitrite additive is no longer available. Does anyone know of a chemical additive that would increase the efficacy and usable life of our caustic solution? We use the caustic solution at an elevated temp in a tooling bath approximately 100 gallon batches. Without the additive, the life of the batch is around 3 weeks. With our old additive, the life was almost 2 months.

Comment: Why add some additive to a $10$% $\ce{NaOH}$ solution ? Such a solution reacts quickly and strongly with aluminum residues from steel tooling. And it will not react with the steel itself. So why ?

Comment: @Maurice Well, apparently it does "increase the efficacy and usable life of our caustic solution"... Anything can be made better.